# C++ new operator - memory layout

Tags: c++, oop, memory

Is the new operator guaranteed to allocate a continuous chunk of heap memory? I.e. is

```
objects=new Base[1024];
```

in terms of memory allocation the same as

```
objects=(Base*)malloc(1024*sizeof(base));
```

or can there be gaps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the memory will be continuous. In terms of allocation, it's the same as the `malloc` version, but there are several differences (calls to constructor, `new` doesn't return `NULL`, `malloc` doesn't throw exceptions, etc.`).

Note that you can't mix up `new[]` with `delete` or `free`, you have to use `delete[] objects` to free the memory.

Comment: It's not quite the same. The `new[]` version will call the default constructor on each object.

Comment: Sorry, I'm blind today I guess.  The new version will however allocate a bit more space to remember the size of the array so `delete[]` can call the correct number of destructors. It's of course a minor difference in space.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y that comment is missleading. It will allocate precisely as much as you instruct it to. The implementation **may** *reserve* some memory to keep track of the length, but that's an implementation detail. It appears nowhere in the standard.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: it's not like `free` magically know the size of the allocated region. A similar construct is needed there.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe.  The `new` operator does two things: it calls the `operator new` function, which will return a contiguous block of memory, adequately aligned for all possible types (except when it doesn't; e.g. a misused placement new); it then calls the constructor of the object, which can do just about anything.  Including allocating additional blocks, which will not be contiguous with the first.

Answer (score 0):

If the `new` operator is not overloaded, yes the allocated block of memory is contiguous. But if it's overloaded, we can't know (some evil programmers might have overloaded it ? :D)